# Efficient numpy memmap usage

Tags: python, numpy, cython, mmap, numpy-memmap

I have a large structured binary file (2.1GB) with a section of header and of required data in each packet, this is being read into the volatile memory for faster access. To do this I am currently using numpy's memmap facility with custom datatype to retrieve the required data set, using the cython procedure shown below,

```
    #Code for illustration only 
 
    data1     = np.memmap(file_name,  dtype = dt, mode = 'c')
    data2     = np.memmap(file_name1, dtype = dt, mode = 'c')

    cdef np.ndarray lin1                =       np.zeros((len(data1)), dtype = np.int32)
    cdef np.ndarray lin2                =       np.zeros((len(data2)), dtype = np.int32)
    cdef int i
    for i in range(len(data1)):
        lin1[i]                         =       data1['Packet'][i]
        lin2[i]                         =       data2['Packet'][i]
```

Now, ideally I would want to spend as little time on this IO operation as possible, as further processing of the data set is computationally quite large and there are multiple set of such files available that needs similar processing. This IO operation takes up close to ~40% of the code execution time. This is even higher if the data are present on a different partition of the same disk.

Is there a more efficient or less time consuming way to do this?

Comment: Based on the limited information shown, it looks like your data is not contiguous on disk. It would go faster if it were, so perhaps you should reconsider your data structure. While you ponder that, please post a [mcve]

Comment: What's the difference compared to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68286225/cython-memory-allocation (i.e. please don't keep posting the same question multiple times)